# Global average for multiple params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, average, dry

I m triying to do an average of multiple params. For 1 unique params all works perfectly but I can't do multiple params average. Can you help me ?

```
@ratingservice = Comment.where(:camping_id => params[:id]).average(:service).to_i
       @ratingcommunication = Comment.where(:camping_id => params[:id]).average(:communication).to_i
       @ratingqualiteprix = Comment.where(:camping_id => params[:id]).average(:qualiteprix).to_i
       @ratinganimation = Comment.where(:camping_id => params[:id]).average(:animation).to_i
       @ratingproprete = Comment.where(:camping_id => params[:id]).average(:proprete).to_i
       @ratingsituation = Comment.where(:camping_id => params[:id]).average(:situation).to_i
```

For multiple params this command doesnt work : uninitialized constant

```
@ratingall = Commment.where(:camping_id => params[:id]).average(:service, :communication, :qualiteprix, :animation, :proprete, :situation).to_i
```

By the way this method isn't DRY for sure....

Comment: Personally, not tried yet. `Comment.where(:camping_id => params[:id]).group(: service, ...)` see what returns then get sum/avg etc... let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[average](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-average) only accepts one column name.

You'll probably have to write a SQL query if you want to calculate the average of the averages directly.

For a DRYer version of your code :

```
where_camping = Comment.where(:camping_id => params[:id])
@ratings = [:service, :communication, :qualiteprix, :animation, :proprete, :situation].map{|key|
  [key, where_camping.average(key).to_i]
}.to_h
```

@ratings is now a Hash with e.g. {:service => 3, :communication => 2, ...}

To get the average of averages:

```
@ratingall = @ratings.values.sum.to_f/ratings.size
```

To get a specific rating in your view :

```
@ratings[:service]
```

To iterate over the ratings :

```
@ratings.each do |category,rating|
  # Use category and rating variables.
end
```

Comment: One question more, if i want to display average for "service" or other params separate how can id this in my view ?

Comment: that's great :) Thanks !

Comment: Tout le plaisir est pour moi ;)

Comment: C'est super sympa dans tous les cas :)